# Is scala as succinct with regular expressions like Ruby?

Tags: regex, scala

In Ruby if you wanted to replace multiple ! marks to a single ! you can do:

```
 text.gsub!(/!+/, '!')
```

Does scala have a succinct way of doing something similar?

Comment: The answers show some ways of approximating this. But Scala has no direct lexical support for `Regex` literals. The suffix `.r` is pretty much as good, I think, and eliminates some complexity in the lexical analyzer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can simply do:

```
text = text.replaceAll("!+", "!")
```

Note that Scala strings are instances of [`java.lang.String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html).

Comment: Say I was to perform 10 such operations on the text variable, is there a way to do it so it doesn't create a new String variable every time?

Comment: No. Strings are immutable.

Comment: If you're just concerned about the length of your code you could just chain them: `text.replaceAll("!+", "!").replaceAll("foo", "bar")`.

Comment: @user1361315 you want to avoid recompiling the regex. See the other answer and use pattern.r to compile once.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use a regular expression, this will do. The `.r` in Scala turns the `String` into a [Regex](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.3/index.html#scala.util.matching.Regex).

```
scala> val s = "This is exciting!!!"
s: String = This is exciting!!!

scala> "!+".r.replaceAllIn(s, "!")
res14: String = This is exciting!
```

Answer (score 0):

In thinking about this question, the thought that it would be possible to create a Scala 2.10+ string interpolator to somewhat streamline the creation of Regex instances relative to the current `.r` method. As soon as it occurred to me, I figured someone must have already given this a try, and in fact they had.

Check it out: [Scala Regex StringContext](https://github.com/qerub/scala-regex-stringcontext)

Comment: I'm sure there are other evolved examples, but https://github.com/som-snytt/regextractor